# Make Pylint recognise variables defined by modifying __dict__

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I have a codebase (that I did not write and can't modify) where objects are created with their names given as strings in the following way:

```
import sys

class A:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        sys.modules['__main__'].__dict__[name] = self
```

The objects are then defined and accessed as

```
A('test')
print(test.name)
```

However, when I open this in Visual Studio Code, all of these variables are marked as undefined by pylint. Does anyone know of a good workaround to get Pylint not to recognise these objects? I could turn off undefined variable warnings altogether, but I would like to still have the benefits of variable checks, if possible.

Comment: This isn't really a coding issue, I think you would be able to get more help in the VSCode support site

Comment: That looks simply impossible. Pylint does [static analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis) (no program execution) and therefore cannot know that `A('test')` defines the global variable `test`. I imagine you could create a linting tool where you hardcode the rule "`A` defines globals", but have a hard time imagining such a tool already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to make Pylint work in this case. Pylint does static analysis and this would require dynamic analysis.